# File Transfer protocol used in com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Is the transfer protocol used in com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest a secred one ?
If not is there any secured alternative ?

Comment: Please, read the rules of this community.

Comment: Hi...WC to SO! Kindly go through..https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. This will help you to understand how to create a better OP in SO

Answer (score 0):

AWS S3 API should be using the HTTPS protocol, so it should be secure